# I want to bind checkbox against enum values

Tags: angular

I want to bind enum values to the checkbox group in HTML page.When i select any labelled checkbox , integer value against it should be get store in array.

i have this enum.

```
typesOfAccess :any = [
{1 : 'Create user '},{2 : 'Delete user '},
{3 : 'Update user '},{4 : 'Create Group'},
{5 : 'Update user '},{6 : 'delete group'}];


<div class="access-content">
     <mat-selection-list accessRight>
       <mat-list-option ngFor="let a of typesOfAccess">
          {{a}}
      </mat-list-option>
   </mat-selection-list>
</div>
```

I want to store and remove corresponding numeric value of the each checkbox on the select and de-select.

Comment: This is not an enum

Comment: To wit ^, [_this_ is an enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html).

Comment: @yanky_cranky actually i am new to angular as well as javascript,but i want to implement in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

component.html

```
<mat-selection-list #list [(ngModel)]="selectedOptions" (ngModelChange)="onNgModelChange($event)">
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let tta of taskTypeAreas; let i = index" [value]="i+1">
  {{tta[i+1]}}
</mat-list-option>
```

component.ts

```
taskTypeAreas:any = [
{1 : 'Create user '},{2 : 'Delete user '},
{3 : 'Update user '},{4 : 'Create Group'},
{5 : 'Update user '},{6 : 'delete group'}];

selectedOptions: [] = [];
```